# The proper way to handle popup closing

Tags: javascript, dom, popup, cross-domain, dom-events

I'm looking for close event for popup. I've found one [for XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL/Events#Common_XUL_events), but I need it for HTML.

Popup has `closed` property.

```
>>> var popup = open('http://example.com/', 'popup', 'height=400,width=500');
>>> popup.closed
false
```

Well, I can [check it once at half second](http://elv1s.ru/files/html+css/popup-onclose.html).

```
function open_popup() {
  var popup = open('http://example.com/', 'popup', 'height=450,width=450');
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if (popup.closed) {
      alert('popup closed!');
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 500);
}
```

I've tested it on Chrome 4.0.249.27, Opera 10.10, Safari 4.0.4, and Firefox 3.5.5. All works fine.

But setInterval bother me. It is ugly. Is there a better way of doing this?

**UPDATE:**
I use popups for authentication dialog (oAuth, actually). I wanna send some data to parent window after popup close (through postMessage).

Page inside popup from another domain. So, I can not add any event (`unload`) to it due security restrictions.

I can not use iframe due to iframe buster script. So, I can not use any fancy jQuery modal dialogs.

I can not edit *anything* inside popup.

Comment: gah! I saw the way to do this just the other day! In the newly created window there is a property, I think a property of document that allows you to refer back to the original window that created, and say run a function. It works much like popup.closed in your example, except the other way around

Comment: aha, found it - answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the `unload` event, take a look at [Javascript: Popups](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-popup-window.phtml)

**edit**: as you've said you cannot edit anything inside the popup, there really aren't any options left. I believe your current `setInterval` code does the job just fine. You should ask yourself if realtime detection of the popup closing is absolutely critical. That 500 milliseconds timer certainly won't strain hardly any resources or bring someones computer to its knees.

Answer (score 0):

I have used jQuery Dialog and it has a close event

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/.

Am not sure if I understand your question right,why do you want to use the timer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use window.opener in the pop-up window. i.e. something like:

```
onunload = opener.alert('popup closed');
```

or

```
onunload = opener.nameOfAFunction();
```

Comment: Because you don't want to, or don't have access to the file?

You could do something like
    popup.onunload = opener.alert('popup closed');
if you don't have access to the file. If you don't want to, then why not. If another reason why you can't, please explain.

Comment: I don't have access to the file. "File" actually something like https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=rpfbncv&oauth_nonce=123456800&oauth_timestamp=1257965400&oauth_consumer_key=ef1uGeq4fP9vbnDXQAtlN0IcKvY8RTef0MztKJfBRYacPiuYmQXFdi10DOU3WSDVfn7MQw5basdrn92urX47wlD3F6G4oOA6JHE6&oauth_signature_method=plaintext&oauth_signature=1e782b9c13315e30d2fbac12348942cc9db674f2%26&oauth_version=1.0&xoauth_lang_pref=en-us&oauth_callback=http://mysite.com/callbackurl.php