# making link disappear from window.open pop up

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have link that opens a window, with `window.open("mytest.aspx");` the problem i am having is that when they close that pop up window I need to hide that link on the parent page. So basically, how can I hide the link (which is an anchor) on the parent page from the pop up that was opened with window.open() ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, JavaScript Code onclick event of the link:

```
function OpenPopup()
{
  document.getElementById("linkID").style.visibility='hidden';
  window.open("mytest.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I need to make it so that it closes from the pop up when they click a button to close it... this will hide the link when its opening the pop up.

Comment: @user1416156 So what you are saying is that you want the user to be able to continuously click the link while the popup is open?

Comment: Yes because while they go through a wizard, if they reach the end,only then I must hide the link

Answer (score 0):

I miss understood the question. You can do following:

```
function Popup(){
  parentWindow = this;
  window.open('mytest.aspx');  
}
```

Have another function in parent window:

```
function hideLink(){
  $("#linkID").hide()
}
```

Then before the popup call the following function:

```
parentWindow.hideLink();
```

I apologize for previous answer.

Comment: I dont understand how this can be related to be able to hide the link from the pop up?

Comment: And what does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at this similar post - [The proper way to handle popup closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853875/the-proper-way-to-handle-popup-closing)

The OP and accepted answer use `setInterval` to poll the popup.  Once closed, execute your 'hide anchor' logic.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the onunload event to hide the link when the window is closed only, 'hr1' is your link id on the opener page :

On your popped up page

```
function CloseOpener(){ 
window.opener.document.getElementById('hr1').style.display='none'; 
}
```

And then on the same popped up page:

```
<body onunload="CloseOpener();"> </body>
```

Or using a separate button on the same page to trigger the closing:

```
 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="CloseOpener();"/>
```

I have tested this and it works on my installed browsers but still there are some considerations to make while using this event, you can have an insight on it here: [onunload not working in Chrome and safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843565/onunload-not-working-in-chrome-and-safari)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to try something like this:

```
var popup = window.open('mytest.aspx');
popup.onbeforeunload = function(){ 
   document.getElementById("theLink").style.visibility='hidden';   
}
```

Note though that this assumes the popup page is in the same domain as the parent.